# Orchard CMS SMTP credentials have to be set to 'null'

Tags: smtp, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am using the Workflow and Email Messaging modules to send an email to myself when a user fills out a custom form. In the logs I get a "5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender" without requiring credentials, but it works just fine when I set it to require credentials and I use 'null' for the username and password.

I am migrating the site from a Sitefinity site on the same server with the same SMTP settings and it works fine without requiring credentials in Sitefinity. The only reason I mention this is because it seemed strange to me that I could use SMTP on Sitefinity without requiring credentials but on on Orchard, and only through a bunch of testing did I figure out that I could use 'null' as the user name and password.

Comment: Bug filed https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/21195